# SharePoint 2010 - Change metadata without changing approval date or status?

Tags: 2010, metadata

I work in SharePoint 2010 managing a document library; and we realized the other day that a majority of the documents within it need some metadata changed.  This isn't a small change, it's about 900 documents.

All of the documents are on a six month review cycle; and that date is linked to the approval date.  Any change to the document is set up so that it sets it back to pending (so I'd need to reapprove it) which would change the review date.

Is there a way to set it via admin rights or workflows to be able to update metadata **without** putting the document back into pending status?

Basically, can I change the metadata without changing any other aspect of the document, so it's not sent back into the approval workflow?

Bonus frustration:  The workflow needs to remain active (if we can) so anyone uploading documents can send them for approval.

Thanks!